# Prove that any normal subgroup of $A_n$ has an element with a fixed point.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

As part of a proof that $A_n$ is simple for all $n\ge5$ I want to prove that, if $H\triangleleft A_n$ (where $n\ge 6$), then $H$ contains some $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(k)=k$ for some $k$.

What is the simplest way to do so?

I saw a proof of $A_n$ being simple for $n\ge 5$ which proves that there must be an element which fixes $n$. This is a natural step to proving that any normal subgroup of $A_n$ is a normal subgroup of $A_{n-1}$. However, I realised there is no need to specify whether $n$ gets fixed or some other value, so I thought this could make the proof simpler.

The proof I was looking at: arbital.com/p/alternating_group_is_simple

Comment: This question is missing context! Could you explain why you want to do that? It does not seem obvious. On the contrary, if $H$ is nontrivial then it must act transitively.

Comment: @DerekHolt I saw a proof of $A_n$ being simple for $n\ge 5$ which proves that there must be an element which fixes $n$. This is a natural step to proving that any normal subgroup of $A_n$ is a normal subgroup of $A_{n-1}$. However, I realised there is no need to specify whether $n$ gets fixed or some other value, so I thought this could make the proof simpler.

Comment: The proof I was looking at: https://arbital.com/p/alternating_group_is_simple/

Comment: OK, I understand the question now. But the proof in your link looks very short and  straightforward, so I can't see why you would want to look for an alternative.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm just trying to make the proof as simple as possible

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include these details. Not everyone checks the comments.

Comment: @Shaun Ok, edited :)